# Jquery change the value of an input for form submission

Tags: jquery, forms

I have created a form field that receives a value from a dropdown option.

On the front end, when a dropdown option is selected, the correct data appears; however, when you look at the inspector the value is still empty and when the form is submitted, no data is captured.

Here is the code:

```
$(window).load(function()  {
  $("#position").appendTo(".form-columns-1");
  $("#position").change(function(){
    var positionValue = $("option:selected").val();
    $('input[name=bdm_position]').val(positionValue); 

  }); 
});
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: PS this is using a hubspot form

Comment: The inspector may not necessarily update certain attributes as you make changes. Additionally, the "option:selected" line is not specific to any select tag. If ('#position') is a select, then, I would suggest something like this: $("#position").change(function(e) {
    var positionValue = $(e.target).find("option:selected").val();
    $('input[name=bdm_position]').val(positionValue); 
  });

Also, if $('input[name=bdm_position]') is a select, this is the wrong selector for it. You'll need to use either $(':input[name=bdm_position]') or $('select[name=bdm_position]').

Comment: input[name=bdm_position] is a text field.  this is the only select on the page so i did not use an id to identify it.  again, it works on the front end, but when you submit the form, the value is not passed

Answer (score 0):

## Edit

> *"...it works on the front end, but when you submit the form, the value is not passed."*

A `<form>` is now added which will submit to a live test server, its response is redirected to the `<iframe>` located below the `<form>`. Review the demo:

1. Select an `<option>` of the `<select>`...
2. ...note the `<input>` value is set to the `<select>` value.
3. Next click the <kbd>Submit</kbd> button...
4. ...note the server response printed in the `<iframe>` below:

> ```
>    {
>       "args": {}, 
>       "data": "", 
>        "files": {}, 
>        "form": {
>          "bdm_position": "B"
>      }, 
>      "headers": {...
> ```

This result is expected if you selected "B"

---

Didn't see how `$('#position')` existed before it was appended, so I guessed. The problem is that a `<select>s` value is accessed directly to the tag itself:

```
$('select').val()
```

---

### Demo

```js
var pos = $(`<select id='position'>
  <option val='A'>A</option>
  <option val='B'>B</option>
  <option val='C'>C</option>
  <option val='D'>D</option>
</select>`);



pos.appendTo(".form-columns-1");

pos.on('change', function() {

  $('input[name=bdm_position]').val($(this).val());

});
```

```html
<form id='ui' action='https://httpbin.org/post' method='post' target='view'>
  <fieldset class='form-columns-1'>

  </fieldset>

  <input name='bdm_position'><input type='submit'>
</form>
<iframe name='view'></iframe>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```